# Matlab data cursor does not work

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-figure

I have installed matlab2014b on fedora20 and I have a problem when I try to use data cursor on the figures while I zoom in, in the figure, it doesn't show the value on the position that I clicked on, and it's very further away. what can cause this problem? I have Nvidia driver installed and I have also CUDA on my computer, so I suppose something is messing up with the graphics but can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I doubt many people can help you here. What about official Matlab support?

Comment: try using the command "datacursormode" from MATLAB command prompt. Then goto the figure and mark the point you want. Then If you want to zoom in at that point, then from MATLAB command prompt type "zoom on"... Again to go back to data cursor mode type "datacursormode" in MATLAB command prompt and select the point you want. This works for me on Ubuntu and I totally use command prompt even in MATLAB. If it is not working please post the error message. You have to be in data cursor mode to show the value of the point you clicked on. Hope this helps.